# Generic detail viewResult must be called with either an object pk or a slug

Tags: django

I got this error shown as title. According to document, I added "slug_url_kwarg = 'result'", (result is the app name). It doesn't work, then I added "def get_object(self):", it returns the error as "id is a KeyError"

1. The database it has created by itself a primary ket:"id", so I used this "id" as slug_field. Is this correct?
2. Do you think if it is necessary for me to use UpdateView? I want the html to display a result after submiting the form(using ajax)?

Thans in advance for your reply.

**url**

```
url(r'^result_list/$',ResultView.as_view(),name='result'),
```

**views.py**

```
class ResultView(UpdateView):
    context_object_name = 'result_list'
    template_name = 'result_list.html'
    form_class = InputForm
    slug_field = 'result.id' ---here means the pk,right?
    slug_url_kwarg = 'result'



    def get_queryset(self):
        return Result.objects.all()

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = InputForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if self.request.is_ajax():
                company = form.cleaned_data['company']
                region = form.cleaned_data['region']

                queryset=Result.objects.filter(region=region)
                return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(to_json),mimetype='application/json')
        else:
             return HttpResponse(form.errors)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ResultView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["sales"] = self.get_queryset().aggregate(Sum('sales'))

    def get_object(self):
        object = get_object_or_404(Result,id=self.kwargs['id'])  <!here is not correct--->
        return object
```

**traceback**

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\views\generic\edit.py" in get
  267.         self.object = self.get_object()
File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\project\result\views.py" in get_object
  54.         object = get_object_or_404(Result,id=self.kwargs['id'])

Exception Type: KeyError at /result_list/
Exception Value: 'id'
```

Comment: You're not passing any id in your URL. How are you expecting this view to work out which object you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to map the url pattern, you don't need to specify slug_field and slug_url_kwarg in your case:

```
url(r'^dupont_list/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', DupontView.as_view(), name='dupont'),
```

Comment: Hi @iago1460,there is one thing I don't understand: the final result I want to display is an "aggregate" calculated result, it is not the value of certain "id" row. But after removing the get_object (self), it will display the error as title, then can I realize the desired function?

Comment: Aggregate generates a dictionary "{'sales_sum': 99.99 }", so access to that value like this:
context["sales"] = self.get_queryset().aggregate(Sum('sales'))['sales_sum']